# Setting width for columns in a table when the number of columns is variable

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an angular 8 project at work. I have a page which has a `View Only` mode and an `Edit` mode. This page has a `table` which displays a certain type of records. I am supposed to add a column of checkboxes as the first column in the table when `Edit` mode is enabled. As per the current code the width of each column was set like below

```js
.data-table tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 16%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 15%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 5%;
}
```

So when my checkboxes appear in `Edit` mode, the formatting gets messed up, because now each existing column is pushed ahead by a place and gets assigned wrong width. Other than adding `id` for each `th` tag  and then specifying the css for each, I can't think of anything else. Please suggest any other possible way to do this.

Comment: Add the `EDIT` column so it always exists but then hide that column with CSS `display:none;` when not on the edit page.

Comment: That's great, I set my comment as an answer with a basic example `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From My Comment

Add the `EDIT` column so it always exists but then hide that column with `CSS display:none;` when not on the edit page.

**View Page:**

```
<table class='without-edit'> 
    <tr>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>Hosehead</td>
      <td>Trapdoor</td>
      <td>Tartarse</td>
      <td>Flippant</td>
      <td>Crappery</td>
      <td>Scottish</td>
      <td>Dorkeley</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Edit Page:**

```
<table class='with-edit'> 
    <tr>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>Hosehead</td>
      <td>Trapdoor</td>
      <td>Tartarse</td>
      <td>Flippant</td>
      <td>Crappery</td>
      <td>Scottish</td>
      <td>Dorkeley</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.without-edit tr td:first-of-type {
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting width from scss file use attribute binding like below

```
<th [style.width]="percentage + '%'"></th>
```

here percentage may be a number depending on your edit condition

or else try like this

add a class to your table by using ngClass directive like

```
<table [ngClass]="{ 'with-edit': isEdit , 'without-edit': !isEdit  }"></table>

.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 16%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 15%;
}
.data-table .with-edit tr th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 5%;
}


.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 16%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 15%;
}
.data-table .without-edit tr th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Edit column header as td instead of th then skip td by changing your css to nth-of-type:

```
<td>Edit</td><th>Col 1</th>
```

css:

```
   .data-table tr th:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 20%;
  }
  .data-table tr th:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 10%;
  }
```

Then amend your css to add header styles to that td also if needed.